# Inline JavaScript and CSS with webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack for bundling resources. Currently it bundle both the CSS and JS files into a separate file called bundle.js. How can I make both the JS and CSS embedded inline in html file?

```
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import {HotModuleReplacementPlugin} from 'webpack';

export default {
  entry: {app: './test/dev'},
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
      {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
  devtool: 'eval-source-map'
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm using grunt-processhtml https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml to solve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

Comment: This doesnt work any more, looks like theres some crappy npm package versioning and compatibility going on, surprise surprise

Answer (score 9):

Use **InlineChunkHtmlPlugin** from **react-dev-utils**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: { filename: 'client-bundle.js' },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/client-bundle/]),
  ],
  // ...
};
```

*where *"/client-bundle/"* regex should match output filename

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-dev-utils#new-inlinechunkhtmlpluginhtmlwebpackplugin-htmlwebpackplugin-tests-regex

---

for inline **css** you need additional rules object:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/style.css', './src/client.js'],
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader', // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'css-loader', // Translates CSS into CommonJS
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: it does not seem like working for me, it does not seem to inline the js files.

Comment: This worked beautifully, but is there a way to add the inline js in the body:

Comment: @JonathanDsouza, I think you just `inject: 'body'`?

Answer (score 5):

**For Webpack 5:**

Neither

- `InlineChunkHtmlPlugin` from `react-dev-utils` (due to some obscure error where something was `undefined`)

nor

- `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` (due to Webpack 5 incompatibility)

worked for me, so i found a different solution that only uses `html-webpack-plugin` (which **is** compatible with Webpack 5) and the modification of the template you supply for `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

*template.html:*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script defer="defer">
            <% /*
            The following line is a workaround for scripts that insert .js code into the generated .html file.
            Because this is set here, "inject: false" is set in webpack-config.js in plugins.HtmlWebpackPlugin
            */ %>
            <%= compilation.assets[webpackConfig.output.filename].source() %>
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

*webpack-config.js:*

```js
// ...
// your other webpack-config code
//...
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: "./myOutPath",
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "My Web App",
      template: "template.html",
      // this is a workaround for the injection of the code from the output file into the .html
      // the injection will be handled in the template file
      inject: false,
    })
  ],
```

In this case, only the content of the one output file set in your Webpack config (here: `bundle.js`) gets injected into the HTML file. But i guess you get the general point.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @daddaidudu's answer, my build files had hash values, so adding hash to the key worked for me.

```
<style type="text/css">
    <%= compilation.assets['default.bundle.css?hash=' + compilation.hash].source() %>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

html-webpack-inline-source-plugin doesn't work anymore, you can use script-ext-html-webpack-plugin instead.

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            cache: false
        }),
        new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inline: [/\.js$/],
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: `script-ext-html-webpack-plugin` has been deprecated by the author and won't have compatibility with webpack 5.

Comment: The inline functionally is still working with webpack5.

Comment: Doesn't work with `html-webpack-plugin: "5"`
https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json#L65