# How to use webpack to inline css and js into html and remove unused styles

Tags: webpack

I have a single HTML file and some SASS and JS, and for Production I want to bundle these together into a single HTML file which contains the SASS compiled into CSS into an inline `<style>` element, and the JS combined and minified into an inline `<script>` element. Not, where the css is embedded in the JS and added to the DOM via JS or in separate files.

I've got as far as getting the SASS compiled into `.css` and `<link`ed to and the JS into a `<script src="`ed `.js`. I've also got PurgeCss working (I think - it's stripping a lot of probably unused selectors).

How do I inline the CSS and JS in their own tags inside the HTML?

Please don't just say to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline-css-webpack-plugin or reference [Inline JavaScript and CSS with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555511/inline-javascript-and-css-with-webpack), because this seems to be plagued with errors and version/dependency mismatches. If this is the best answer, how do you actually make it work? What versions of all the dependencies actually work together?

Here is my `webpack.config` which works as far as I've got:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin')

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const glob = require('glob');

const purgecssFromHtml = require('purgecss-from-html');

const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
}

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            //'style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                //importLoaders: 1,
                url: false
                },
            },
            'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css"
    }),
    new PurgecssPlugin({
      paths: glob.sync(`${PATHS.src}/*.*`),
      styleExtensions: ['.css'],
      whitelist: ['whitelisted'],
      extractors: [
        {
          extractor: purgecssFromHtml,
          extensions: ['html']
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

`src/index.js`:

```
import "./scss/theme.scss";
import "./file1.js"
import "./file2.js"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing around with Webpack for the last couple of weeks.

I'm still fairly new Webpack, but have a side HTML template project where I've been using it which may help: https://github.com/JustAGuyCoding/spotlight-webpack, especially since it's a working example.

The webpack config looks like this:

```
const path                      = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin         = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin }    = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin      = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("style-ext-html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin                = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/spotlight.js',
    output: {
        path        : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename    : 'spotlight.[contenthash].js',
    },

    /* Development - webmode. */
    // devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    // devServer: {
    //     contentBase: './dist',
    // },

    plugins: [

        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            dry     : false,
            verbose : true,
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title           : 'Spotlight',
            filename        : 'index.html',
            template        : './src/spotlight.html',

            scriptLoading   : 'defer',
            inject          : false,
                /* Prevent automatic insertion of CSS link tag, as it will inlined, but specify postiion  of bundled.js in the lodash template. */

            /* _Lodash template params. */
            static: false
        }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename        : 'spotlight.css',
            chunkFilename   : '[id].css',
        }),

        new StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            position: 'head-bottom',
            minify: true
        }),

        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: './license.txt', to: '../dist/license.txt' },
                { from: './notice.txt', to: '../dist/notice.txt' },
                { from: './readme_html.md', to: '../dist/readme.md' },
            ],
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [

            /* Images - uses require(lodash template), HtmlWebpackPlugin and file-loader to pickup and process(copy to dist).  */
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: "images/[name].[ext]",
                    esModule: false
                    /* Fixes [object,object] appearing on spotlight.html template when require(file) processed by lodash in HtmlWebpackPlugin.*/
                }
            },

            /* SASS-CSS-Extract-Internalise\Inline - uses StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin*/
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, they key was the `style-ext-html-webpack-plugin` and its sister `script-ext-html-webpack-plugin`

Comment: Too bad `style-ext-html-webpack-plugin` is no longer maintained. We're back to square 1. @AndrewBullock