# How to make webpack bundle js directly in script tag, not via src

Tags: javascript, webpack

My **webpack.config.js** file now is:

```
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
    mode: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',

    // This is necessary because Figma's 'eval' works differently than normal eval
    devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',

    entry: {
        ui: './src/ui.js', // The entry point for your UI code
        code: './src/code.js', // The entry point for your plugin code
    },

    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Compile into a folder called "dist"
    },

    // Tells Webpack to generate "ui.html" and to inline "ui.ts" into it
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/ui.html',
            filename: 'ui.html',
            inlineSource: '.(js)$',
            chunks: ['ui'],
        })
    ],
})
```

**and one of the file it complies is:**

**ui.html:** (this is a target file for the current question)

```
<head>
    <script defer="defer" src="ui.js"></script>
</head>
<h2>Figma auto layout</h2><p>Count: <input id="count" value="5"></p>
<button id="create">Create</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button><br>
<button id="create-structure">Create structure</button>
```

**I want ui.html to bundle resulting html file like this:**

```
<h2>Figma auto layout</h2><p>Count: <input id="count" value="5"></p>
<button id="create">Create</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button><br>
<button id="create-structure">Create structure</button>
++ <script>
++     // here is js code from ui.js
++ </script>
```

**How could I make webpack compile this way?**

**EDIT 1**

If I use

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/ui.html',
        filename: 'ui.html',
        inlineSource: '.(js)$',
        chunks: ['ui'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

it returns me an error (I have this plugin already installed)

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHooks' of undefined
```

I know that it requires webpack 5. My webpack version is ``--webpack@5.33.2`

**Any alternatives for html-webpack-inline-source-plugin?**

Comment: In order to use the `inlineSource` option on `html-webpack-plugin`, you need to install the `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` (see [here](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin)).

Comment: They have it installed already?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555511/inline-javascript-and-css-with-webpack and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206486/how-to-use-webpack-to-inline-css-and-js-into-html-and-remove-unused-styles

Comment: @SuperStormer please see edit 1

Comment: @superhawk610 please see edit 1

Answer (score 3):

Here's two solutions I found after facing a similar problem:

1. You can use the `InlineChunkHtmlPlugin` from `react-dev-utils`, the advantage being that it's plug-and-play... for the most part! In my case, the script I was injecting contained a `</script>`, which broke the page. You can control where the script will be emitted (head, body, etc.) by modifying the `inject` property of the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`

[For more info, have a read here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-dev-utils#new-inlinechunkhtmlpluginhtmlwebpackplugin-htmlwebpackplugin-tests-regex)

2. You can inject the script (s) using an HTML template, which you can provide to `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. For example, this template inlines all JS and CSS assets into the webpage:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title #{htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title}
  body
    each cssFile in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css
      style !{compilation.assets[cssFile.substr(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath.length)].source()}
    each jsFile in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js
      script !{compilation.assets[jsFile.substr(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath.length)].source()}
```

[For more info, have a read here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use InlineChunkHtmlPlugin from react-dev-utils

```
new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/.*/]);
```